# Rounding to 6 decimal places using Math.round method in Java android

Tags: java, android, decimal, rounding

I'm using

```
double i2 = value * 2.23694;
i2 = (double)(Math.round(i2 * 100)) / 100;
```

for rounding doubles. But it rounds to only 2 decimal places.

I want it to be 6 decimal places.

Is there any way to use `Math.round` and have 6 decimal places?

Comment: What do you expect? If you round a number, you're removing all decimal places. After that, when you're dividing it with 100, the only possible result is two decimal places!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are casting things to `Integer`s which will ruin any rounding. To use `double`s, use a decimal point (i.e `100.0` instead of `100`). And if you want it with 6 decimals, use `1000000.0` like this:

```
 double i2 = value * 2.23694; 
 i2 = Math.round(i2*1000000.0)/1000000.0;
```

But generally I think [DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is a more elegant solution (guessing you want it rounded only to present it):

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.000000");
String formattedValue = f.format(i2);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the values for displaying just use below method for rounding to 6 digits

```
double a = 12.345694895;
String str = String.format("%.6f", a );
```

Answer (score 1):

double value = 12.3464367843;
        double rounded = (double) Math.round(value * 1000000) / 1000000;

output:12.346437

Comment: Not a good solution. This would fail if value = 12.000000003464367843 as it would return 12.0